# Parsing JSON String with JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Trying to parse the JSON content from AWS SQS.

First converting a string to JSON String and then to JSON Object. What is the correct way to handle this scenario ?

```
<script>

// JSON from SQS 
var x='{"Message":"{\"default\":{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"value1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"value2\\\"}\"}","Timestamp":"2018-03-20T03:21:32.136Z"}';
x1=JSON.stringify(x);
var obj = JSON.parse(x1);
console.log(obj.Message); // undefined
alert(obj["Message"]); // undefined 
</script>
```

Comment: `parse` from string `stringify` to a string.. :)

Comment: What on earth are you doing to need all that escaping? Is the JSON rendered directly into your JS code, or is it retrieved by AJAX?

Comment: Firstly, you're stringifying a string. Secondly, you did not declare a variable for x1. Thirdly, your string is not a valid string. Open developers tool in chrome and run those expressions step by step and you'll see the error

Comment: that is the response I am getting from AWS SQS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea why you are trying to `JSON.stringify()` a string. It's already a string!

The string you have got is not valid JSON either and needs a few extra `\\`s in it. Where did you get it from? Or was it a typo.

```
var x='{"Message":"{\\\"default\\\":{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"value1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"value2\\\"}\\\"}","Timestamp":"2018-03-20T03:21:32.136Z"}';
                    ^__________^_____________________________________________________________^
```

Just parse the JSON you do have then realise that `obj.Message` is just more JSON that could be `JSON.parse()`d

```js
// JSON
var x = '{"Message":"{\\\"default\\\":{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"value1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"value2\\\"}\\\"}","Timestamp":"2018-03-20T03:21:32.136Z"}';
//Parse JSON
var obj = JSON.parse(x);
console.log(obj.Message); // string formatted as yet more JSON
```

Answer (score 1):

The string is not right. It should be like

```
var x='{"Message":"{\\\"default\\\":{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"value1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"value2\\\"}\\\"}","Timestamp":"2018-03-20T03:21:32.136Z"}';
```

You are stringifying the x, which is already string

```
x1=JSON.stringify(x); //Not ok
```